# keep gridview sort after clicking asp linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have tried a number of solutions to get this working, but I could not find one that it working for me. I am a beginner at programming in C# with ASP.net, and I would appreciate any help that I can get.

Currently, my gridview allows me to sort, if I click on the column header, and this sorts it by ascending to descending order. However, when I click a link button i.e. one of the buttons in the 'flags' column of my programme, it does highlight that option (it is supposed to do it), but it doesn't keep the sort - I want it to keep the sort after this has been clicked. Would someone be able to help with this please?

Here is my aspx code (this is in asp:GridView):

```
<%--Flags column--%>                    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Flags" ItemStyle-Width="34px" SortExpression="sortFlag">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="width:34px">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HidSortFlag" Value='<%#Eval("sortFlag") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidAmended" Value='<%#Eval("Amended") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPayAnyway" Value='<%#Eval("PaymentOverrideFlag") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidQueries" Value='<%#Eval("QueryCount") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSupplierRefCount" Value='<%#Eval("SupplierRefCount") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnElementRef" Value='<%# Eval("SuggestedMatches") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="flagQueries" runat="server" Text="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Comments and Queries'></span>" OnClick="flagQueries_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StatementLineId") +";"+Eval("SupplierRef") +";" + Eval("SuggestedMatches")%>' > </asp:LinkButton><br />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="flagAmends" runat="server" Text="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Related Booking Has Been Amended' ></span>"  OnClick="flagAmends_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StatementLineId")  %>'></asp:LinkButton><br />
                        <asp:LinkButton id="flagPayments" runat="server" Text="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Pay Anyway'></span>" OnClick="flagPayments_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StatementLineId") + ";" +Eval("SuggestedMatches")%>'></asp:LinkButton> <br />

                    </div>                         
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the code behind which does the sort:

```
        protected void gridSummary_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the sort field is being used or a new sort
        if (ViewState["summarySortField"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["summarySortField"] = e.SortExpression;
        }
        else if (ViewState["summarySortField"].ToString() != e.SortExpression)
        {
            ViewState["summaryDirectionState"] = null;
            ViewState["summarySortField"] = e.SortExpression;
        }

        summaryDirection = summaryDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
        string sortingDirection = summaryDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "Desc" : "Asc";

        DataView summaryView = LoadStatement();

        summaryView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, sortingDirection);
        //Session["SortedView"] = summaryView;
        gridSummary.DataSource = summaryView;
        gridSummary.DataBind();
        //ColourFlags();
    }
    public SortDirection summaryDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["summaryDirectionState"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["summaryDirectionState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            return (SortDirection)ViewState["summaryDirectionState"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["summaryDirectionState"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void gridDetail_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the sort field is being used or a new sort
        if (ViewState["detailSortField"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["detailSortField"] = e.SortExpression;
        }
        else if (ViewState["detailSortField"].ToString() != e.SortExpression)
        {
            ViewState["detailDirectionState"] = null;
            ViewState["detailSortField"] = e.SortExpression;
        }

        detailDirection = detailDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
        string sortingDirection = detailDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "Desc" : "Asc";

        //string gets toggle error field in order to add the colour red to certain columns
        DataView detailView = LoadDetails(Session["arg"].ToString());
        string[] args = Session["arg"].ToString().Split(';');
        string status = args[0];

        detailView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, sortingDirection);
        //Session["SortedView"] = summaryView;
        gridDetail.DataSource = detailView;
        gridDetail.DataBind();
        ColourFlags();
        ToggleErrorFields(string.IsNullOrEmpty(status));
    }

    public SortDirection detailDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["detailDirectionState"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["detailDirectionState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            return (SortDirection)ViewState["detailDirectionState"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["detailDirectionState"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Here is the click event for one of the flags:

```
       protected void flagAmends_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton faBtn = sender as LinkButton;
        int lineId = int.Parse(faBtn.CommandArgument);

        using (SpamEntities spam = new SpamEntities())
        {
            SPM_Statement_Lines line = spam.SPM_Statement_Lines.Where(x => x.StatementLineID == lineId).FirstOrDefault();

            line.Amended = !line.Amended;
            spam.SaveChanges();
        }

        //reloads gridview
        LoadDetails(hidStatus.Value + ";" + hidCategory.Value + ";" + lineId);            
    }
```

After the button clicks the button changes colour, and performs the necessary action, however it does not keep its sort - I have been trying to fix this but I have not been successful. I would appreciate any clear step by step solutions.

Comment: Try `summaryView.ToTable();` before binding to the GridView.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I tried adding this in before and after binding 
 (just to see what happens after binding) to GridView, but it did not work. I'm not sure if I explained it clearly - when a user sorts the column, it should show the highlighted flags at the top, and if they click on of the flags, lets say at the bottom of the page, that should move to the sort with the first sort that the user wanted. It allows me to click on the flag, but it doesn't move up to join the sort. @VDWWD